# Iphone: Unhiding a Tab bar and Navigation Bar after Navigation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UItabbarController and inside the first tab a UINavigationController. In interface builder I have set the tab bar and navigation bar as hidden.

When the first screen loads up (which is a UIVewcontroller in the Uinaviagtioncontroller of the first tab) I set an NStimer for 2 seconds. After which it navigates to a second view. Now when this happens I want the navigation bar and tabbar to appear, and it should be animated.

This what I am doing right now.

First UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    splashTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector (action) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)action{
    SecondViewController *m = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:m animated:YES]; 
}
```

Second UIViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But nothing is really happening. Neither the Tabbar or the NavigationBar appears.

Answer (score 1):

Try place the code for your Second View Contoller inside the viewWillAppear method instead of the initWithNibName method and see if that has the desired outcome:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

That way it should be called everytime the view is about to display.